# JSON / Jade - Cannot output JSON variable to Jade template

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

I'm passing some JSON data to a Jade template, but can't seem to print the JSON data to my Jade template. This is an example of the JSON which is stored and passed to the Jade template:

```
{ name: 'Team 1',
  _id: 5134d71192cf972226000003,
  __v: 0,
  key: 1362417425623 }
```

It is passed through to the Jade template like so:

```
res.render('tournamentDetails', { 'tournamentData' : tournamentData, seedsSerialized : JSON.stringify(tournamentData.teams) } );
```

The format of the Jade template is:

```
script(type='text/javascript')
                var seeds = [#{tournamentData.teams}];
```

I'm trying to access this variable `seeds` in a seperate JavaScript file, but cannot seem to access them. I have been testing using `alert` to test what is in seeds in the JavaScript file and it is not the teams.

This is the generated HTML from the Jade too:

```
var seeds = [{ name: 'Team 1',
  _id: 5134d71192cf972226000003,
  __v: 0,
  key: 1362417425623 },{ name: 'Team 2',
  _id: 5139dc66b48da58d0e000001,
  __v: 0,
  key: 1362746470498 },{ name: 'Team 3',
  _id: 5139dda45f1598440f000001,
  __v: 0,
  key: 1362746788314 },{ name: 'Team 4',
  _id: 513b2c66cfd50dce11000001,
  __v: 0,
  key: 1362832486554 }];
```

How would I access the teams in a JavaScript file? I am wanting to output the `names` of the `teams` to the Jade template.

Comment: I really would like to help, but just a few more clarifications. Is the problem that `seeds` doesn't get generated correctly in the output from Jade, or is it that you can't access `seeds` from somewhere else? If the output is wrong, could you give an example of the expected output? Also, why are you creating `seedsSerialized`, but then not even using it to assign `var seeds = !{seedsSerialized};`?

Comment: @BretCopeland I'm trying to pass the JSON to the Jade template, which I believe it has done as this variable `seeds` gives the output I stated above. I basically have a set of brackets I am trying to put the team names into. In the seperate JS file, I can't seem to access `seeds`, when I try to output `seeds` it is blank, nothing there. So yes the problem is that I cannot access it from my JS file. I'm not sure with the `seedsSerialized`, a friend was helping with that line of code and this is how it was left, sorry for that.

Comment: Did you make sure that `seeds` is being declared before including any additional scripts which use that variable? (In other words, the order that you include scripts on a page matters.)

Comment: Aren't the values for _id invalid in JSON. Wouldn't they need to be wrapped in quotes to make them strings?

Comment: @BretCopeland Correct, the only other scripts being loaded don't have any variable `seeds` in them.

Comment: @Travis `_id` is generated automatically when it is saved to the database using `mongoose` so I assume it's fine? But either way, the `name` is stored and output fine

Comment: I didn't even notice that, Travis is right, just plain hex isn't valid unless it's prefaced with `0x`. Try using what I suggested of `var seeds = !{seedsSerialized};` and see if that parses correctly.

Comment: @BretCopeland Yes it parses the same way still, not sure how I would even begin to change the `_id` issue as `mongoose` is creating it automatically. Shouldn't effect what I am trying to achieve though?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer exactly, but it was too long for a comment...

Look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KvXTA/

```
var seeds = [{ name: 'Team 1',
  _id: 5134d71192cf972226000003,
  __v: 0,
  key: 1362417425623 },{ name: 'Team 2',
  _id: 5139dc66b48da58d0e000001,
  __v: 0,
  key: 1362746470498 },{ name: 'Team 3',
  _id: 5139dda45f1598440f000001,
  __v: 0,
  key: 1362746788314 },{ name: 'Team 4',
  _id: 513b2c66cfd50dce11000001,
  __v: 0,
  key: 1362832486554 }];

console.log(seeds);
```

notice how the console outputs

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

That's because of the _id fields. I'm surprised you say that the serialized version has the same problem, since it should have surrounded the ID's in quotes. If you don't need the ID's at all, you can get rid of them in the serialized version by using a replacer function.

```
var seedsSerialized = JSON.stringify(teams, function (key, val) {
    return key === '_id' ? undefined : val;
);
res.render('tournamentDetails', { seedsSerialized: seedsSerialized });
```

Then use that serialized version to initialize `seeds` in the template.

```
script
    var seeds = !{seedsSerialized};
```

My earlier comment about order of including scripts wasn't a concern that maybe another file was creating a seeds variable, it was that you might have been including a file which used `seeds` before `seeds` was actually declared.

For example:

```
<script src='logSeeds.js'></script>
<script>
    var seeds = [ ... ];
</script>
```

where logSeeds.js is:

```
console.log(seeds);
```

would obviously output `undefined` since `seeds` hasn't been declared yet. It was just a thought, not necessarily your situation.

Comment: `var seeds = JSON.stringify(#{tournamentData.teams}, function (key, val) {
   return key === '_id' ? undefined : val;
  });` I've replaced my code on the Jade template with this in order to try and move forward, but still can't get anything to appear, if I try and put `alert(seeds)` in the JS file nothing appears. Don't quite understand what is going on, I just want to be able to print the names of the teams on the Jade template using this JS file, seems impossible the amount of hours I have tried to fix this.

Comment: The JSON.stringify code was not intended for using in the template. You need to perform the stringify in the Node.js code, and then send the stringified version to the template. Inside the template, the stringify code will fail just like the original code.

Comment: Apologies, added this into the node.js code so that the Jade template only has `var seeds = #{seedsSerialized}` with your code used. Putting an alert in the JS code of `alert(seeds[0].name)` or even `seeds`, can't get anything to appear. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did some testing, for some reason if I put on the Jade template itself `#{seeds[i]}`. Whatever `i` is, it actually gives me that letter of the seeds JSON, so `seeds[5]` gives me the a of `name`, wierd?

Comment: Okay, then try `var seeds = JSON.parse(!{seedsSerialized});`, although I wouldn't think the output would be wrapped in quotes. Can you repost the new output of the template?

Comment: Trying it without `JSON.parse` allowed me to output `seeds[0]` using the JS file which output everything about 1 team, outputting `seeds[0].name` however gave me `undefined`. Trying it with `JSON.parse` gave me nothing. I noticed printing `{#seedsSerialized}` using the Jade template that there are only quotes around `name` still, and quotes around each `team` in the list

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28059/discussion-between-bret-copeland-and-germainelol)